# Como verificar se existe uma Fonte já instalada

Tags: c#

Tenho um programa em C# que verifica se existe uma fonte já instalada ou não, porém não está funcionando direito:

Estou tentando com o seguinte código

`if (File.Exists(@"C:\Windwos\Fonts\Agency FB"))`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia como posso verificar pelo nome da fonte?

Comment: Mas dá algum erro? Ou diz sempre que não encontra?

Comment: Não ocorre erro nenhum, apenas retorna `false` no `if`.

Comment: Esse seu caminho "Windwos" está errado, o correto deveria ser "C:\Windows\Fonts".

Comment: Nem tem correto nesse caso, pois posso instalar e registrar uma fonte em qualquer pasta do sistema. Fonts é a pasta padrão pra isso, mas não é obrigatória. O certo é chamar as funções do OS pra isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pode utilizar a classe [`InstalledFontCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=PT-BR&k=k%28System.Drawing.Text.InstalledFontCollection.%23ctor%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) e procurar se a sua fonte se encontra na coleção:

```
public bool FonteExiste(string aMinhaFonte)
{
    var fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
    return fonts.Families.Any(f => f.Name.Equals(aMinhaFonte, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

A performance pode variar dado que e necessário correr a coleção para encontrar a fonte. Uma solução alternativa será:

```
public bool FonteExiste(string aMinhaFonte) 
{
    using (Font fontTester = new Font(aMinhaFonte,
                                      10,
                                      FontStyle.Regular,
                                      GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
    {
        return fontTester.Name.Equals(aMinhaFonte, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Esta forma baseia-se no facto de que se a fonte que procurar não existir, a classe [`Font`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=PT-BR&k=k%28System.Drawing.Font%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) vai colocar a fonte *Microsoft Sans Serif* como *default*. Dai testar se o nome da fonte criada e igual ao nome da fonte desejada.

No entanto desta forma só vai procurar fontes que tenho o estilo normal (ao invés de **negrito**/*itálico*/etc) definido.

Para concluir, se a performance não for critica, prefira a primeira solução dado que e mais completa.

**EDIT**:
Os dois exemplos no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/G2cgx8).

Comment: muito obrigado, tava testando a primeira opção, vou dar uma testada na segunda também.